# How to reuse the variable provided by Twitter-bootstrap using MopaBootstrapBundle?

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap

I use [Symfony2.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/2.0/) with [MopaBootstrapBundle v2.x_sf2.0](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/tree/v2.x_sf2.0/) which provide the Twitter-bootstrap. Actually, I include the main Less file like in the [documentation](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/tree/v2.x_sf2.0#Using). This file include all Less files from the Twitter-bootstrap. My problem is that I can't access to the mixins provided by the TwitterBootstrap in others file.

```
    {% stylesheets filter='less
       '@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less'
       '@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/myfile.less'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Which is the best way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the mixins and variables in your bundle is to copy the mopabootstrap.less file to `@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/bootstrap.less` and amend the paths to the imports to point to MopabootstrapBundle. I would also add an additional last import called `@import "bootstrap-override.less";` for styling of the additional elements.

Your stylesheet block would then look like the following:

```
{% stylesheets filter='less
   '@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/bootstrap.less'
%}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

In case you need to change one of the core bootstrap files (you probably need variables.less), just copy them to your project and change the import path in bootstrap.less.

Comment: I try to manage this issue with your solution but I have not yet succeeded to import the file.
I use this url @import "/vendor/bundles/Mopa/BootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less"; to import all file from MopaBootstrapBundle and I got no error from the server so I think the path is correct.
Do you know what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You have given it the absolute path to the less file, remember that the less file is compiled before reaching the browser, so you should change it to the relative path `@import '../../.././../../../vendor/bundles/Mopa/BootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.‌​less'`. Not tested, but should work.

Comment: I got a 500 error. I try with ../../../../../../vendor/bundles/Mopa/BootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/m‌​opabootstrapbundle from /src/Btask/DashboardBundle/Resources/public/less/main.less

Comment: Hmm, try compiling it manually from the command line (`lessc bootstrap.less`), and make sure it works there - you'll probably see a meaningful error message.

Comment: I've got a parse error "at /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.0/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:390:69: '../../../../../../vendor/bundles/Mopa/BootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less' wasn't found. (Less::ParseError)". I tried to change the relative path without success.

Comment: works with this path in /src/Nice/MyBundle/Resources/public/less/main.less

@import '../vendor/bundles/Mopa/BootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/m‌​o‌​pabootstrapbundle.less';

Thank cvaldemar for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I could not access the variables in variables.less in my custom less files. So I have created a bundle to help solve this, maybe someone will find it useful.

https://github.com/realtyhub/BootstrapBundle

https://packagist.org/packages/realtyhub/bootstrap-bundle